# Schedule task on a shiny application

Tags: r, scheduled-tasks, shiny

I am working on an application using shiny, as part of my project I need to scrape some data from a website on a daily basis.
 Is it possible to schedule a job to be done every 12 hours, using cron or a similar utility?
I am using the free shiny server hosting server

Comment: @jdharrison i don't think that it is a duplicate becuse this will not work on a shiny server host

Comment: What is special about a shiny server host. You just want  to run a cron job. Also it is considered bad form to double post and not at least indicate that you have https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/6shCY_4aIRs

Comment: Any solution about it? Like the author I will run a script like this in the shinyapps.io , and I don't think I have access to cron there. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I really don't recommend doing this in shiny. Yes, invalidateLater is meant to schedule a reactive to be run again later , but your usecase is abusing that function. Also, a single shiny app session is not meant to be running 24/7, it will likely die between those 12 hours.

You should probably use a cronjob (the cronjob can call an R script, that's 100% legitimate)

Comment: would you provides some example for rescheduled task on shiny?

Comment: As per my answer, I **do not** recommend doing scheduled tasks with shiny

Comment: @DeanAttali - Forgive my ignorance, why is a single shiny app session not meant to be running 24/7?

Comment: It *can* be, but it would just be taking up resources and accumulating them indefinitely

Comment: These kinds of answers I find are too short and don't explain to people like me who are trying to find a solution why invalidateLater would be a bad idea with a shiny app.  Since stack overflow questions come up in a lot of google searches they need to be more detailed

Answer (score 2):

There is a specific method within Shiny doind exactly that:

invalidateLater

See also http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/invalidateLater.html.