# call myFunction daily, at specific time, in shiny?

Tags: r, timer, shiny

im looking for a way to call a function daily at %H:%M in server.R of a deployed shiny app.
using an infinite loop to "watch the clock" is probably a sin and doesnt work. any ideas?

#### ui.R

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage("floou", textOutput("foo")))
```

#### server.R

```
library(shiny)
myFunction <- function() {...}
repeat {  # same behavior with while (T)
  # Sys.sleep(60)  # also tried sleeping
  if (format(as.POSIXlt(Sys.time(), tz = "GMT"), "%H:%M") == "21:00") {
    myFunction()  # func not called + rendering blocked -> approach not working
  }
}
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$foo <- renderText("not rendering with infinite loop")
})
```

Comment: You mean like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24880355/schedule-task-on-a-shiny-application)?

Comment: I highly suggest not doing this with shiny. A Shiny session is not meant to be open 24/7. What you want to do should be done with a cronjob (the cronjob can call an R script)

Comment: @daattali thanks for the hint. have scheduled a script via windows task scheduler on my local pc..works fine, but that process isnt fully autark though as it requires my pc to be running and online..how should i set things up for such a repetitive task to run autonomously?

Comment: If the problem is that your computer isn't always on, then you can buy a server from amazon EC2 or digitalocean ($5/month) and that server will always be on

Comment: thanks @daattali goin 2 get me a server then

Answer (score 0):

It may be done in this way.
But you have to hold an open session.

**server.R**

```
timeStop <- "22:45:20"
trick <- reactiveValues()
trick$catch <- FALSE

  observe({
    invalidateLater(200, session)
    if (strftime(Sys.time(),  format="%H:%M:%S") > timeStop) {
      trick$toFire <- "after"
    } else if (strftime(Sys.time(),  format="%H:%M:%S") < timeStop){
      trick$toFire <- "before"
    } else if(strftime(Sys.time(),  format="%H:%M:%S") == timeStop & trick$catch == FALSE){
      trick$toFire <- "exact"  
}
  })

  observe({
    invalidateLater(200, session)
    if (trick$toFire == "exact") {
           trick$toFire <- "after"
            trick$catch <- TRUE
            Sys.sleep(1)
          #your code or functions
            trick$catch <- FALSE
        } 
  })
```