# Shiny Application to check something at a specified time

Tags: r, vbscript, shiny

I was wondering if there was a way to get Shiny to check something at a specified time each day if it is running. Now I know this is not recommended and I have read through

1. [Schedule task on a shiny application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24880355/schedule-task-on-a-shiny-application)
2. [Schedule R script using cron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10116411/schedule-r-script-using-cron)
3. [call myFunction daily, at specific time, in shiny?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40602754/call-myfunction-daily-at-specific-time-in-shiny)

as well as I am aware of the reactiveTimer function in Shiny. However, I have developed and deployed my Shiny App as a desktop app instead of a url and consequently my colleagues like to leave it open. Here is the basic example of what I am trying to:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage()
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  test <- reactiveValues(value = format(as.POSIXlt(Sys.time()), "%H:%M"))
  observeEvent(test$value == "7:15", {
    stopApp()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The reason I would like the application to stop at a scheduled time is because I want the application to check for an update and re-launch after it updates. I suppose it should only stop if their is something to update but the above is a simpler idea of what I am trying to accomplish.

Is there anyway to get shiny to execute some code at a specific time? I know reactiveTimer is an option but this performs a task after a specified amount of time but not at a specific time each day.

Another option is if I could get a vbs script or even just a different r script to close the Shiny App but I have not been able to figure out how to do that either. Any advice or ideas would be a big help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does the trick (a little verbose, but works)
**You need to set the variable `timeStop` (HH:MM:SS)**

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("info")
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  ## Variable to set the time when app stops automatically (HH:MM:SS)
  timeStop <- "22:47:20"

  toStop <- as.POSIXct(timeStop, format="%H:%M:%S")
  if (Sys.time() > toStop) {
    toStop <- toStop + 86400
  }
  secsToStop <- round(as.numeric(difftime(toStop, Sys.time(), units = "secs")) * 1000)
  timeToStop <- reactiveTimer(secsToStop)
  trick <- reactiveValues()
  trick$toFire <- FALSE

  observeEvent(timeToStop(), {
    if (trick$toFire) {
      stopApp()
    } else {
      trick$toFire <- TRUE
    }
  })

  output$info <- renderUI({
    h2(paste("App will stop automatically at ", toStop))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Hi there, I would like to understand why is the reactivevalue used here? Why not observeEvent timeToStop then just stopApp() ?